# In SBT, can one automatically name-mangle privately used packages?

Tags: java, scala, jar, versioning, sbt

Consider the common case of using a specific versioned jar to implement a method, but not exposing any types from that jar in the public or protected API (only in method signatures of private methods).

Now what I want is an automatic compile-time linking of this code by name-mangling the original package name and replacing it in the generated code within SBT (again: I want to add a plugin to SBT or a setting in the build.sbt that does this on every `sbt compile`).

The goal of this is to avoid classpath errors with multiple possibly incompatible versions of a classes with the same package/class name. Note: in the situation I describe above, inlining or this name-mangling should always work and allow one to side-step version-hell (at the cost of larger jars).

Comment: Sounds like it might be a use case for [Scala Macros](http://scalamacros.org/)?

Comment: This is what OSGi is commonly used for. OSGi uses clever tricks with class loaders instead of name mangling, but it achieves the same effect.

Comment: I don't know of any way to do the sbt equivalent of class relocation from the maven-shade-plugin: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/class-relocation.html

Comment: Jarjar: http://code.google.com/p/jarjar/ seems like exactly what I want (with the rename rules), but I don't see an sbt plugin or example of how to get this to work.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like the sort of thing that [ProGuard](http://proguard.sourceforge.net) would be able to do. There is an [SBT ProGuard plugin](https://github.com/siasia/xsbt-proguard-plugin) but it doesn't appear to be actively maintained.

If I were tackling this problem, personally speaking I would look to a custom classloader for a solution rather than name mangling.

Comment: Please explain "personally speaking I would look to a custom classloader"

Comment: ProGuard is a bytecode 'uglifier', not a mangler. The purpose of mangling is strictly for making multiple version compatible, not accelerate or obfuscate. see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling for definition